# showDialog deprecated. What's the alternative?

Tags: android, dialog

Is there something else that should be called?

```
showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
```

It's in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html) but says *deprecated* in Eclipse.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

> public final void showDialog (int id) Added in API level 1
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 13. Use the new DialogFragment
>   class with FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older
>   platforms through the Android compatibility package.
>
> Simple version of showDialog(int, Bundle) that does not take any
>   arguments. Simply calls showDialog(int, Bundle) with null arguments.

**Why**

- A fragment that displays a dialog window, floating on top of its activity's window. This fragment contains a Dialog object, which it displays as appropriate based on the fragment's state. Control of the dialog (deciding when to show, hide, dismiss it) should be done through the API here, not with direct calls on the dialog.
- Here is a nice discussion
  [Android DialogFragment vs Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog)
- Another nice discussion
  [DialogFragment advantages over AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765127/dialogfragment-advantages-over-alertdialog)

**How to solve?**

- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

**More**

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Answer (score 8):

From [`Activity#showDialog(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int%29):

> **This method is deprecated.**
>   Use the new [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) class with [`FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

Comment: So instead of calling a simple function, you have to implement yet another custom class? *sigh*

Comment: Deprecated isn't the same thing as gone.  If a deprecated function still works, and an alternative isn't available on the older platforms I want to support, I go ahead and use it anyway.

Comment: @Edward I think that there's an alternative for the older platforms, check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 6):

To display dialog box, you can use the following code. This is to display a simple AlertDialog box with multiple check boxes:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); .
            alertDialog.setTitle("this is a dialog box ");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ok ive wrote this 'ok' here" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "cancel ' comment same as ok'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
            alertDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which] +(isChecked?"clicked'again i've wrrten this click'":"unchecked"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
```

### Heading

Whereas if you are using the showDialog function  to display different dialog box or anything  as per the arguments passed, you can create a self function and can call it under the `onClickListener()` function. Something like:

```
 public CharSequence[] items={"google","Apple","Kaye"};
public boolean[] checkedItems=new boolean[items.length];
Button bt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            display(0);             
        }       
    });
}
```

and add the code of dialog box given above in the function definition.

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me. Easy fix but probably not a preferred way.

```
public void onClick (View v) {
    createdDialog(0).show(); // Instead of showDialog(0);
}

protected Dialog createdDialog(int id) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: but how to implements the LIstener on that method? Let say for the Date & Time dialog.... @MishaLee

Comment: Android does it for you when you define onClick attribute in xml.

Comment: @gumuruh Android does Listener for you when you define onClick attribute in xml like this: android:onClick="onClick" and then the method above in Java. If you need a custom Listener then you have to define one yourself. More details are in this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.keshav.datePicker_With_Hide_Future_Past_Date;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ed_date;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ed_date=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_date);

        ed_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                year=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                final DatePickerDialog   mDatePicker =new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday)
                    {
                              ed_date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month+1).append("-").append(day));
                            int month_k=selectedmonth+1;

                    }
                },year, month, day);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");
                // TODO Hide Future Date Here
                mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

                // TODO Hide Past Date Here
                //  mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });
    }
}


// Its Working
```