# android: how do I override Back button press?

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment

I have a number of EditText lines on a UI where the user enters some data.  The user enters a Date (from a DatePicker fragment) on the fListenerEditText line.  The focus is then returned to the first EditText line which is cListenerEditText.  For the default Back button behavior, if the user then presses the Back button, the Activity would close and the Date data would be immediately lost, and the user is returned to the previous Activity.

In my case, I would like to launch a Dialog fragment that asks the user if they want to discard the Date they previously entered at fListenerEditText.  If the user clicks the "OK" button, the data is discarded, the Activity closes and the user returns to the previous activity.  Note in my case, the soft keyboard is not open when the user presses the Back button key.

How do I use a FocusListener and a Back button listener together?  What am I missing here?

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListenerEditText cListenerEditText, dListenerEditText, eListenerEditText, fListenerEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activity_edit); 

    cListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.CEditText);
    dListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.DEditText);
    eListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.EEditText);
    fListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.FEditText);

    final int stringDueDate = fListenerEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ", "").length();

    cListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && fListenerEditText.getText().length() > 0) {
            // add some type of Back button listener here.    
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Override method `onBackPressed()` and check the input length of field `fListenerEditText`. If its not `0` then show confirmation `dialog` otherwise call `super.onBackPressed()` to `finish` activity to show `previous` one from activity-stack.
2. If your click on `OK` button, then just finish `EditActivity`.

**Update `EditActivity` as below:**

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListenerEditText cListenerEditText, dListenerEditText, eListenerEditText, fListenerEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activity_edit);

        cListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.CEditText);
        dListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.DEditText);
        eListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.EEditText);
        fListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.FEditText);

        ..........
        ...............
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (cListenerEditText.hasFocus() && fListenerEditText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            // Show dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Discard?");
            builder.setMessage("Your change will be discarded");

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Finish activity
                    finish();
                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do nothing
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**FYI,** If you want to do extra operation depending on the focus then use `cListenerEditText.hasFocus()` to check the focus and to change the focus after picking date just use `cListenerEditText.requestFocus()` and `fListenerEditText.clearFocus()`.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Nice.  Ok only issue is that I need to somehow handle the fact that the the focus will be on cListenerEditText line and not on the fListenerEditText line when the user presses the Back button.  So I need a FocusListener for cListernerEditText and test the length of fListenerEditText.  Any thoughts on how to achieve?

Comment: check my updated answer. Use condition: `if (cListenerEditText.hasFocus() && fListenerEditText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {......}`

Comment: Ok I see.  And add onBackPressed() NOT in onCreate() section correct?  Just add in the main part of the Activity?

Comment: app crashes at "alert.show();" line.  Logcat says "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Use `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` OR `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditActivity.this);`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: That did the trick.  Is the AlertDialog.Builder preferred versus launching a DialogFragment because it is simple?

Comment: As you are showing simple dialog, you can use `AlertDialog.Builder`. For better understanding check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765127/dialogfragment-advantages-over-alertdialog

Comment: Very good, I will study.  Answer upvoted and accepted.  You mentioned AlertDialog.Builder(this) OR ...(EditActivity.this).  What is difference between these two and how should I decide which to use?

Comment: This represents the current activity context. In SO there are lots of question and answers regarding `Context`. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966601/what-is-different-between-mainactivity-this-vs-getapplicationcontext

Comment: I appreciate your time and expertise to answer the original question and the follow-up questions.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can show new Dialog which asks if the user wants to discard the changes or keep them in **OnBackpress()** and **onOptionSelected()**

```
cListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && fListenerEditText.getText().length() > 0) {
            // add some type of Back button listener here.  
              onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    });

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Your dialog title")
        .setMessage("Do you want to discard the old changes")
        .setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(){
           // your task
          }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("yes", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                EditActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }).create().show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but where do I put the onBackPressed code so that it is only handled if the cListenerEditText has focus and stringDueDate > 0?

Comment: call onBackPressed from your if condition. check the updated answer.

Comment: The cListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener is in the onCreate() section.  Do I put your onBackPressed() in the onCreate() section or below it in the main section of the Activity?