# Adding custom layout in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to I use my xml as a layout for my dialog? This class is used to show a dialog but the problem is i want to set my own layout.

```
 public static void showRateDialog(final Context mContext, final SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    tv.setText("If you enjoy using " + APP_TITLE + ", please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!");
    tv.setWidth(240);
    tv.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 10);
    ll.addView(tv);

    Button b1 = new Button(mContext);
    b1.setText("Rate " + APP_TITLE);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ll.addView(b1);

    Button b2 = new Button(mContext);
    b2.setText("Remind me later");
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ll.addView(b2);

    Button b3 = new Button(mContext);
    b3.setText("No, thanks");
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editor != null) {
                editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ll.addView(b3);

    dialog.setContentView(ll);
    dialog.show();
}
```

I want it to have 3 buttons and a picture. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Your question is about `AlertDialog` but you have written code for a `DIalog`. `AlertDialog` is an implementation of `Dialog` with pre attached buttons and more. See [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view) Its not the same problem but code there is useful for your problem .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set custom layout to your dialog like below:

Create a custom layout file:

**custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity:

```
// custom dialog
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
dialog.setTitle("Title");

// set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text.setText("Text view 1");

TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text2);
text.setText("Text view 2");
dialog.show();
```

Comment: So when does my app need the draw over other apps permission? I remember with this type of dialogs you need that

Comment: No permission is required for custom dialog

Comment: Im asking because its being called from a different class

Answer (score 3):

> DialogFragment is now the canonical way to display overlays; using Dialog directly is [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765411)

**Usage**

> Custom View

```
<!-- fragment_edit_name.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_your_name" android:text="Your name" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_your_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and DialogFragment will be

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
// ...

public class EditNameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private EditText mEditText;

    public EditNameDialogFragment() {
        // Empty constructor is required for DialogFragment
                // Make sure not to add arguments to the constructor
                // Use `newInstance` instead as shown below
    }

    public static EditNameDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
        EditNameDialogFragment frag = new EditNameDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Get field from view
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_your_name);
        // Fetch arguments from bundle and set title
        String title = getArguments().getString("title", "Enter Name");
        getDialog().setTitle(title);
        // Show soft keyboard automatically and request focus to field
        mEditText.requestFocus();
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and showing the dialog in an Activity:

```
public class DialogDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      showEditDialog();
  }

  private void showEditDialog() {
      FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
      EditNameDialogFragment editNameDialogFragment = EditNameDialogFragment.newInstance("Some Title");
      editNameDialogFragment.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Custom alert dialog**

```
* using create custom alert dialog box*/

private void Multiple_spinner_alert(int position) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.multiple_spinner_recycler_layout);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    final RecyclerView recycler_spinner = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.recycler_spinner);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recycler_spinner.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
    recycler_spinner.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MultipleSpinnerRecyclerAdapter(context,  getSetList,listPK_ProviderTypeOptions_ID);
    recycler_spinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    final  TextView alert_tv_ok=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_tv_ok);
    onChangeSelectedReceivers();

    alert_tv_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { {

             // do your code 

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

- I am using custom dialog inflate layout like this
- set dialog height and width according to your requirements

it helps you

Answer (score 0):

In your layout resource file make sure the android:layout_width is

`android:layout_height = "wrap_content"`

and not

`android:layout_height = "match_parent"`