# Can I still use AlertDialog in Android for API 17?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

In the following example I have `onCreateDialog` and `showDialog` deprecated.

```
package com.dialogtest;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CharSequence[] items = {"Google", "Apple", "Microsoft"};

    // Declare the boolean array of same size as items
    boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[items.length];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialog(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch (id) {

            case 1:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        //.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setTitle("This is a dialog with some simple text...")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                                "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                        )

                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                                "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                        )

                        .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked,
                                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which, boolean isChecked) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                                items[which] + (isChecked ? " checked!" : " unchecked!"),
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                        ).create();


        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I was suggested to use DialogFragment but I am not so sure.

So I want to know that is it not possible to directly use AlertDialog anymore?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285047/showdialog-deprecated-whats-the-alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285047/showdialog-deprecated-whats-the-alternative)

Comment: deprecated doesn't mean that you can't use them. They are just warning that you should now avoid using those methods as they will be removed in future versions.

Comment: try using Appcompat AlertDialog and i don't think switching to appcompat version will affect you much :)

Comment: But If I am not using Appcompat activity then DialogFrament is only alternative?

Comment: You can use android.app.AlertDialog in your activity 

`AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
alertDialog.setMessage("Hi");
alertDialog.show();`

Comment: @shadygoneinsane: You mean I can put this code in OnClick instead of in onCreateDialog?

Comment: @user963241 check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [reference docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) AlertDialog is a subclass of Dialog that can display one, two or three buttons.

In your case use the below code :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExampleActivity.this);
            //.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    alertDialog.setTitle("This is a dialog with some simple text...")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            )
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            )
            .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which, boolean isChecked) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    items[which] + (isChecked ? " checked!" : " unchecked!"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use alert dialog with appcompact version Click [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html)

Comment: use this one https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html