# The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated in android?

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

The method `showDialog(int)` from the type `Activity` is **deprecated**.

[image]

What's the reason? and how to solve it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog(int)

Comment: or you can also call showDialog with null parameter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**What's the reason?**

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int%29)

[Android DialogFragment vs Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog)

**How to solve it?**

Use the new DialogFragment class with FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Comment: Date Picker example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895606/android-datepicker-and-datepicker-dialog/16429329#16429329