# Popup window using Fragment

Tags: android, popup, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I want to create a pop-up window (with black transparent background around it) that would appear above the application activity screen (by clicking on a button). This pop-up would contain a video player, a list of videos to be played and some other elements.
This pop-up has to be a fragment since I need to re-use it from other app fragments.

So my question is : what is the best way to achieve that? I personally see 2 options :

1) adding the pop-up as a fragment on the layout and to show + activate it whenever I need. But in that case, how can I put a black transparent background around it that would fill the whole screen?

2) using DialogFragment but it seems that this class is not very well-designed for this kind of stuff.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DialogFragments are the suggested way to launch Dialog views from within a Fragment, so this is the solution I would suggest for you.

You can do pretty much anything you need within the DialogFragment.  You will be in full control of the UI using this method.

Here is a SO discussion of the same point, with good info: [Android DialogFragment vs Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog)