# difference between Dialog and DialogFragment in android?

Tags: android, dialog, dialogfragment

Upon reviewing the docs in android I've noticed the classes: [`Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)  and `DialogFragment`([standard](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), [v4](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html)). The Tutorials seem to use the terms interchangeably, thus i'm confused as hell about their differences.

Tell me if i'm right with my understanding: a `DialogFragment`, is in essence, a wrapper that handle life-cycle events, while returning an Object of Type `Dialog`, which is the actual UI Object?

Comment: `Dialog` and `DialogFragment` aren't part of the support v7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android DialogFragment vs Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog)

Comment: in v7 there are AppCompatDialog, and AppCompatDialogFragment @SMR

Comment: @SMR i've read that thread. it didn't explain what i was looking for, otherwise i wouldn't have made this post

Comment: according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/package-summary.html) the `AppCompatDialog` and `AppCompatDialogFragment` use AppCompat themes. not sure if there is any other difference