# How to set up a custom listener in a custom dialog for android?

Tags: android, dialog, listener

I'm currently having trouble setting up my custom listener. I just want to pass a string from my dialog to my fragment (where I set up the dialog). I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARezg1D9Zd0.

At minute 10:38, he sets up the listener.
This only problem is that in this, he uses DialogFragment, but I'm extending dialog and I don't know how to attach the context to the listener.

I've tried to set it up in `onAttachedToWindow()` and in the dialog constructor but it crashes.

What should I actually do?

I'd also appreciate it if someone could explain what the difference is between:

onAttachedToWindow() vs. onAttach(Context context).

Thanks!

MY CUSTOM DIALOG BOX:

```
public class NewListDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Activity c;
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayout;
    private TextInputEditText editText;
    private LinearLayout dialog_root_view;
    private Animation fade_out;
    private String list_name;

    private NewListDialogListener listener;

    NewListDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        this.c = a;

        //ANOTHER ATTEMPT TO ATTACH CONTEXT TO LISTENER
        //listener = (NewListDialogListener) a.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_list_dialog);

        MaterialButton cancel = findViewById(R.id.dialog_new_list_cancel_button);
        MaterialButton create = findViewById(R.id.dialog_new_list_create_button);
        textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.dialog_text_input_layout);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit_text);
        dialog_root_view = findViewById(R.id.dialog_root);
        fade_out =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.fade_out_dialog);

        editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (isTextValid(editText.getText())) {
                    textInputLayout.setError(null);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        create.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            //Cancel Button
            case R.id.dialog_new_list_cancel_button:
                dialog_root_view.startAnimation(fade_out);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                }, 200);
                break;

            //Create Button
            case R.id.dialog_new_list_create_button:
                if (!isTextValid(editText.getText())) {
                    textInputLayout.setError(c.getString(R.string.dialog_error));
                } else {
                    textInputLayout.setError(null);

                    //record input string
                    list_name = editText.getText().toString();

                    //send information to parent activity
                    //What to put here?
                    listener.createListName(list_name);
                    dismiss();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean isTextValid(@Nullable Editable text) {
        return text != null && text.length() > 0;
    }

    //ATTEMPT TO ATTACH CONTEXT TO LISTENER
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        try {
            listener = (NewListDialogListener) c.getBaseContext();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(c.getBaseContext().toString() + "must implement ExampleDialogListener");
        }
    }

    public interface NewListDialogListener {
        void createListName(String listname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you define a custom dialog then you can declare a method to allow other components call it or listen events on this dialog. Add this method to you custom dialog.

```
public void setNewListDialogListener(NewListDialogListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

**NewListDialog.java**

```
public class NewListDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Activity c;
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayout;
    private TextInputEditText editText;
    private LinearLayout dialog_root_view;
    private Animation fade_out;
    private String list_name;

    private NewListDialogListener listener;

    NewListDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        this.c = a;
    }

    public void setNewListDialogListener(NewListDialogListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_list_dialog);

        MaterialButton cancel = findViewById(R.id.dialog_new_list_cancel_button);
        MaterialButton create = findViewById(R.id.dialog_new_list_create_button);
        textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.dialog_text_input_layout);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit_text);
        dialog_root_view = findViewById(R.id.dialog_root);
        fade_out =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.fade_out_dialog);

        editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (isTextValid(editText.getText())) {
                    textInputLayout.setError(null);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        create.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            //Cancel Button
            case R.id.dialog_new_list_cancel_button:
                dialog_root_view.startAnimation(fade_out);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                }, 200);
                break;

            //Create Button
            case R.id.dialog_new_list_create_button:
                if (!isTextValid(editText.getText())) {
                    textInputLayout.setError(c.getString(R.string.dialog_error));
                } else {
                    textInputLayout.setError(null);

                    //record input string
                    list_name = editText.getText().toString();

                    //send information to parent activity
                    //What to put here?
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.createListName(list_name);
                    }
                    dismiss();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean isTextValid(@Nullable Editable text) {
        return text != null && text.length() > 0;
    }

    public interface NewListDialogListener {
        void createListName(String listname);
    }
}
```

In other components such as an activity which must implements `NewListDialogListener`.

```
NewListDialog dialog = new NewListDialog(this);
dialog.setNewListDialogListener(this);
```

If you don't want the activity implements `NewListDialogListener` then you can pass a listener instead.

```
NewListDialog dialog = new NewListDialog(this);
dialog.setNewListDialogListener(new NewListDialog.NewListDialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void createListName(String listname) {
        // TODO: Your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the help and sorry for the late response!

Answer (score 1):

In android `Fragments` and `Activity` has lifecycles. `Fragments` are hosted inside `Activity` and get the context of host activity via `onattach` method.

On the other hand [`Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog) is extended from `Object` (God class) without any lifecycle and should be treaded as an object.

If your activity is implementing `NewListDialogListener` then you can do

`listener = (NewListDialogListener) a;`

[`onAttachedToWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onAttachedToWindow()) : mean the dialog will be drawn on screen soon

and

`getApplicationContext()` will give you the context object of the application (one per app) which is surely not related with your listener and hence won't work

Reference :

[**Android DialogFragment vs Dialog**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog)

[**Difference between getContext() , getApplicationContext() , getBaseContext() and “this”**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641144/difference-between-getcontext-getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-and)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Appreciate the explanation. I'll need to read some more documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) instead of using listener, in this situation I use RxAndroid to get data from dialogs to activities or fragments.

Just need to create a `PublishSubject` and get the observed data. on activity or fragment :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PublishSubject<String > objectPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    objectPublishSubject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(this::onNext);
    CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(this, objectPublishSubject);
    customDialog.show();
}

private void onNext(String data) {
    Log.i("DIALOG_DATA", data);
}
```

and you can create dialog like this :

public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private PublishSubject<String> subject;
public CustomDialog(@NonNull Context context, PublishSubject<String> subject) {
    super(context);
    this.subject = subject;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    subject.onNext("Data");
    dismiss();
}
```