# The height of the textview in the custom dialog is 0

Tags: android, textview, dialog

I have a custom popup dialog, but the textview didn't show correctly.
For example, I have activity A and activity B, and now I am activity B, and when I back to activity A, my custom popup dialog will show, but sometimes the textview in custom dialog didn't show, and I find that the height of the textview is 0, I don't know why!
Is there anyone who can help me to figure out? thanks!

The code below is the textview that didn't show correctly sometimes!

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/popup_avatar_layout_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nick_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/popup_avatar_layout_margin"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/kcpopup_avatar_kidDialogContext"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="[NickName]" />


public class DialogPopupActivity extends Dialog{}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
setContentView(R.layout.kid_dialog_avatar_layout)
useDialogCustomAvatar();
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I set the text on method useDialogCustomAvatar.
The code below is what I do.

```
TextView nickNameView = findViewById(R.id.nick_name);
nickNameView.setText(title);
```

Comment: Do you set text on the textView somewhere in code? tools:text is just for previewing your layout in the layout editor.

Comment: Yes, I have set text on the textView somewhere.

Comment: Make sure you set it before onCreateDialog is executed (or in that method).

Comment: Yes, I am sure. And I opened the Layout Inspector before, and find that the height of the textView is 0 sometimes.

Comment: Ok, try to update your question with more details - dialog impl. etc.

Comment: And I really have no idea where there is something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Use `DialogFragment` class instead of the `Dialog` class and override `onCreateDialog` method. It is the preferred way how to create a dialog. The `Dialog` class doesn't handle lifecycle events, which can cause the message to not display sometimes.

[Creating Dialog fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#DialogFragment)

[Differences between Dialog and Dialog Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977392/android-dialogfragment-vs-dialog)