# Android: Custom Dialog has wrong dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'm trying to display a dialog with a custom view. The Layout is pretty simple; basicly there are two `LinearLayouts`; every Layout with a `TextView` and an `EditText`.

The Layout i'm using is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ll_element1">    
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Element 1"/>
    <EditText
      android:layout_width="250dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:lines="5"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_element1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Element 2"/>
    <EditText
      android:layout_width="250dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:lines="5"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But if i set it as view of a dialog the looks like this:
[image: Wrong sized dialog]

My Code to show the Dialog is this:

```csharp
var view = this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Custom_Dialog, null);

var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .SetView(view)
            .Create();

dialog.Show();
```

In my opinion width of the Dialog should be smaller so that the Layout fills the dialog.
I've tried several things:

- Using a LinearLayout instead of the RelativeLayout
- Setting all sizes explizit
- Used Dialog instead of AlertDialog

So, what do i have to do to get a correctly sized dialog?

**edit**
Updated the Picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_element1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Element 1"
        android:lines="5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Element 2"
        android:lines="5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your activity

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourCustomdialog);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: You don't need linear inside relative layout. It's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Remove TextView and use `android:hint` on EditText . Put Both `EditText in One LinearLayout` with `vertical Orientation.`

Change `android:layout_width of EditText as fill_parent` as well as its parent too.

Comment: if i set the width of the EditText to fill_parent, then the EditText is stretched to the width of the Dialog; the Problem now is, that the Dialog is very wide; wider than i want

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `lines=5` in your `EditText`, so it is taking the space. Use `dp` instead of `dip`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Now how do you want it to display? Give some reference so that exact problem can be identified.

Comment: The heigth is not the problem; it's the width. (I should have mentioned this explicit in my question). dip is equal to dp.

Comment: If height is not the problem then for width you are setting the constant 250 dip. You can set it to lower values or use wrap content.

Comment: I also tried setting all sizes explizit, but it seems the Dialog ignores them

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers helped me, so here is my solutíon (maybe someone find it useful).

I had similar problem with `NumberPicker` which was displayed in `AlertDialog`. `NumberPicker` had own layout which was defined in relative units (`"match_parent"`, `android:layout_weight`, ...).

Inflating layout without `rootView` results in layout with default parameters so layout size was not as expected. Inflating layout with `rootView` leads to `IllegalStateException`: *"The specified child already has a parent"* when `AlertDialog#create()` is invoked since `create()` method attaches view to the internal dialog layout.

As described in [How to make an alert dialog fill 90% of screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306503/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-fill-90-of-screen-size#answer-6631310) you can override default parameters like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
params.width = 300; // LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT will match dialog_layout which can be stretched to fullwidth.
params.height = 300;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Instead of using fixed width and height in pixels, you can create `dialog_helper.xml` where you define some transparent view in relative units  (`android:id="@+id/dialog_dimension"`), from which you will later copy width and height. Then include this layout into the activity/fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout ....>
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/dialog_helper"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Since this view is contained in activity layout it has "measured" width and height which can be used as dialog parameters:

```
View dialogDim = findViewById(R.id.dialog_dimension);
params.width = dialogDim.getMeasuredWidth();
params.height = dialogDim.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Calculating relative size from `dialog.getWindow().getAttributes()` would not work as it contains some negative value constants (MATCH_PARENT or something else). Therefore, if you want to calculate dialog size relative to display size use [screen metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels#answer-1016941).

Note, after screen rotate the same width and height will be used, therefore I will recommend to wrap your dialog into the `DialogFragment` which is automatically recreated when device configuration is changed, so dialog will be created with updated `dialogDim` according to current screen orientation. Here is a simple example [How to create DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557265/prevent-dialog-dismissal-on-screen-rotation-in-android#answer-15729764).

Previous example contains communication between activity and fragment (activity need to receive message about dialog event). This requires to define custom listener interface + properly override `Fragment#onAttach()` method. All these steps are explained in following article: [Cummunication between Fragment and Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Answer (score -1):

Use builder and add width and height while showing

```
builder.show().getWindow().setLayout(600, 250);
```