# Title of custom dialog always maxes out width

Tags: android, android-layout

My problem is identical to: [Android: Custom Dialog has wrong dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092299/android-custom-dialog-has-wrong-dimensions)

The solution for that was to disable the dialog title, which does work. The problem is I want the dialog title. I am positive the mere presence of the title causes all the extra width: if I set all child views to a known width (say 100 dp) it is still far too wide. As soon as I remove the title it's just fine, but again, I want the title! This has to be a bug, right?

Any ideas? I'm aware I can create a fake title, but I'd rather not.

Thanks!

P.S. - In case it matters (and I don't think it does) I am subclassing android.app.Dialog, not DialogFragment. Subclassing vs using the builder has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I know you would like to figure this out without disabling the Dialog Title, but it's really not an issue if you do that. Just add another view to your dialog layout, at the top, for your title.

No shame Mark! No shame!