# AsyncTask and Dialog which survive device rotation

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask, orientation

I have an AsyncTask which displays a Dialog. I do not want this to disappear when the device is rotated.

My solution is to store it in an Application class, that way it won't die when the Activity dies. When the activity dies I simply dismiss the Dialog, when it resumes I simply show the Dialog.

This appears to work. When the device is rotated, the Dialog disappears and then reappears with the new Activity. The only problem is that after rotation the Dialog does not animate anymore. Whats weirder is that re-rotating to the original orientation causes the animation to continue from where it stopped.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this issue?
Cathal

```
public class OrientationActivity extends Activity {
    MyApplication application;

    public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
          private ProgressDialog dialog;

          public LongOperation(Context context) {
              dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
              dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
              this.dialog.setMessage("Busy!");
              this.dialog.show();
          }

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              while(true){

              }
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {                           
              if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
                  dialog.dismiss();
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        application = (MyApplication) getApplication();

        if(application.longOperation == null) {
            application.longOperation = new LongOperation(this);
            application.longOperation.execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        application.longOperation.dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        application.longOperation.dialog.show();
    }
}

public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
    LongOperation longOperation = null;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent dialog dismissal on screen rotation in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557265/prevent-dialog-dismissal-on-screen-rotation-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it appears that the following is the best solution. Comments are welcome about whether or not this is considered best practice. Please note I have included the v4 support library for backwards compatibility.

My Activity

```
package ie.cathalcoffey.android.orientation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class OrientationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements FireMissilesDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener{
    MyApplication application;
    boolean rotated;
    public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
          private FireMissilesDialogFragment dialog;

          public LongOperation(Context context) {
              dialog = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
              dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
          }

          @Override
          protected void onCancelled() {
              if(dialog != null && dialog.isVisible())
                  dialog.dismiss();
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
          }

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              while(true){

                  if(this.isCancelled())
                      break;

              }

              return null;
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {                           

          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        application = (MyApplication) getApplication();

        if(application.longOperation == null) {
            application.longOperation = new LongOperation(this);
            application.longOperation.execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(application.longOperation != null)
        {
            application.longOperation.cancel(true);
            application.longOperation = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        if(application.longOperation != null)
        {
            application.longOperation.cancel(true);
            application.longOperation = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        if(application.longOperation != null)
        {
            application.longOperation.cancel(true);
            application.longOperation = null;
        }
    }
}
```

My DialogFragment

```
package ie.cathalcoffey.android.orientation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Whatever")
               .setPositiveButton("fire", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(FireMissilesDialogFragment.this);
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(FireMissilesDialogFragment.this);
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

    /* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
     * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
     * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
    public interface NoticeDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
    NoticeDialogListener mListener;

    // Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the NoticeDialogListener
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
    }
}
```

My Application

```
package ie.cathalcoffey.android.orientation;
import ie.cathalcoffey.android.orientation.OrientationActivity.LongOperation;
import android.app.Application;


public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
    LongOperation longOperation = null;
}
```

Finally my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ie.cathalcoffey.android.orientation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".OrientationActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add onConfigurationChanged?

```
@Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

                Log.e("TAG","LANDSCAPE");

            }else{

                Log.e("TAG","PORTRAIT");

            }


        }
```

if you add this you can handle the orientation and if you didn't add this if you changed the orientation the activity will be recreated after you add this the activity won't be recreated but will keep the current state same as the previous orientation

if you have any question feel free to ask me in the comment :)

Comment: I don't think you have read my question very carefully. Your reply has not been helpful. I do not wish to detect orientation change. The solution I posted appears to work perfectly apart from the frozen animation side effect. My question is about this side effect.