# How can I use a `DatePickerDialog` in a FragmentActivity?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application and I have a problem with designing layouts:

I have this code inside a Fragment:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = 
     DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

And I get this compiler error:

```
The method DatePickerDialog(FragmentActivity, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, int, int, int) is undefined for the type UserProfileFragment  UserProfileFragment.java
```

**How can I use a `DatePickerDialog` inside a fragment?**

By the way, "parent" activity extends `SlidingFragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you missed the `new` keyword

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new
     DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

Comment: Wow! Please kill me! ha ha ha

Comment: :) these sort of things happen :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more correct to use `DatePickerFragment` (aka `DatePickerDialog` within `Fragment`) and add it to `FragmentManager` (see `getSupportFragmentManager()`)

Like this you can survive display rotation (see [Prevent dialog dismissal on screen rotation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557265/prevent-dialog-dismissal-on-screen-rotation-in-android) )

Fragment itself

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

Code to show the DatePickerFragment

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

**Dont't forget to change `extends Activity` to `extends FragmentActivity`**