# Dismiss dialog error

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog showing up using this code:

```
 Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("New game")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        clear();
                                    }
                                }).show();
```

but when I rotate my screen i get an error :  `android.view.WindowLeaked`
and i dont know why.
I tried writing `dialog.dismiss()` and `dialog.cancel()`
in the onClick function of the dialog but it didnt work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);
            builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //put your code that needed to be executed when okay is clicked
            dialog.cancel();


            }
            });
            builder1.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
```

Comment: Thank you!, using the `AlertDialog alert11` this way i could dismiss it anywhere, which is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below link of a post on StackOverflow, and read the answer about using DialogFragment and why:

[Prevent dialog dismissal on screen rotation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557265/prevent-dialog-dismissal-on-screen-rotation-in-android)