# How Should I check for internet connectivty and display a "retry" and "cancel" dialog?

Tags: java, android

I want to check for internet connection and if it's available call `getData()` but if it's not available show a dialog with **RETRY** and **CANCEL** options.

If **RETRY** is clicked check for internet connection; if available call `getData` but if it isn't available, show the dialog again (something like looping).

Alternatively, if **CANCEL** is clicked exit the app altogether.

I'm using this class to check for network availability and internet connection:

```
public class NetworkCheck {

    public static boolean isAvailableAndConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean isNetworkAvailable = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
        boolean isNetWorkConnected = isNetworkAvailable && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();

        return isNetWorkConnected;

    }

}
```

And in MainActivity I do this:

```
if (NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(this)) {
            //Caling method to get data
            getData();
        } else {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Failed to load. Please ensure ypu're connected to the internet and try again");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(context)) {
                        alertDialogBuilder.show();
                    } else {
                        getData();
                    }


                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();

                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.show();

        }
```

From the above codes, I have three questions:

1. In line `if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(context)) {` context is being highlighted in red and when I hover it, I see **Cannot resolve symbol 'context'**. If I leave the method empty or type `this` or `getActivity`; Android Studio complains. Which parameter show I pass the method?
2. Calling `finish()` will only kill the activity. Shoudn't the whole app be killed and how?
3. What else am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you're not using fragments, on the place of **context** you could do a workaround like this (first you declare):

```
        final Context mContext;
        mContext = this;
```

Then you substitute **`context`** to **`mContext`**

2) Killing the activity is not a recommendation (you probably already read about Activity Lifecycle), but you could try `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Comment: Where in MainActivity should I declare `final Context mContext;
        mContext = this;` please?

Comment: } else {
final Context mContext;
mContext = this;
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

Comment: I did that and also this: `if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(mContext())) {`  `mContext`  was underlined in red with the info **method call expected**

Comment: Excuse me, but it is accusing **method call expected** because you did not wrote **mContext** but **mContext()** instead, with the parenthesis at the end, giving this the notation of a method, and this is not a method, thus the raising error.

Comment: Thank you Faraday. Best. and thanks to "someone" for the downvote! God bless.

Comment: @MarkKeen, I did. Didn't notice any glitch

Comment: @Faraday thats surprising as it should disappear if the dialog is open unless you do a bit if work and save its status ..

Comment: @MarkKeen, I use a Lollipop device. Which SDK version does it disappear?

Comment: @Faraday - it shouldn't work full stop .. have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557265/prevent-dialog-dismissal-on-screen-rotation-in-android  .. if its working happy days .. don't know why off hand though ... unless you've changed a setting in the manifest `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` .. which BTW don't do!