# Problems with orientation change and EditText on android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a very strange problem: i have an activity with EditText and three buttons and two layout files for handling orientation change. When i start an app in portrait orientation and rotate the device android preserves the portrait orientation layout, but if i start an app in landscape orientation android loads an appropriate landscape layout file, but again preserves landscape layout even after rotating to portrait layout. This happens only with activity containing EditText. What's wrong? Here's my code:
1) Manifest.xml:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".AnalyzeTextActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartScreenActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        />
```

2) portrait

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_analyze_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ADD5F7"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_analysis"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_upload_file"
        android:background="@drawable/button_upload_large"
        android:onClick="onUploadClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_upload_file"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_start_analysis"
        android:background="@drawable/button_start_large"
        android:onClick="onStartClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_start_analysis"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clear_large"
        android:onClick="onClearClicked"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

3) landscape

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_analyze_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ADD5F7"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_analysis"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_text_analysis"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_start_analysis"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_upload_file"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_upload_small"
        android:onClick="onUploadClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text_analysis"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_start_analysis"
        android:background="@drawable/button_start_small"
        android:onClick="onStartClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text_analysis"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_start_analysis"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clear_small"
        android:onClick="onClearClicked"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you share your layout files?

Comment: @Volodymyr Khodonovych  done

Comment: check please answer below

Comment: Can you please share your folder names where you put your both portrait and landscape layout

Comment: @Sumit Pathak  layout and layout-land

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
```

By default configuration changes handle by android, when you define `android:configChanges` in the manifest file then you told android that you will handle all confiChanges in brackets inside your activity, there is special method for that

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

To fix your problem just remove **`orientation`** from your manifest

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|screenLayout"
```

Comment: @
Volodymyr Khodonovych right you are, when i remove orientation from manifest, android loads correct layout file, but i need orientation in my manifest file to preserve ProgressDialog when changing orientation. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Check this question there are few possible approaches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:configChanges="screenSize|screenLayout"` from

```
  `<activity
    android:name=".AnalyzeTextActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
    android:parentActivityName=".StartScreenActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    />`
```

Comment: the same problem - when removing line you suggest i destroy my ProgressDialog. I just need layot files to load properly and ProgressDialog alive.

Comment: Have a look on this solution 
[Prevent dialog dismissal on screen rotation in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15729764/4770978) .