# Android AlertDialog can't rotate

Tags: android, dialog

I have an `activity` and it creates and shows `dialog` in `onCreate`.
The `dialog` is made by `AlertDialog.Builder`.
It shows properly except when I rotate the screen, the `dialog` does not rotate....

How to solve it, thx?

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:name="com.xxx.yyy" android:process=":core" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"> </activity>
```

**Activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently read a similar problem posted by another user. The problem was solved. Maybe it fits to your problem, too. Look here [Android: Dialog etc restore after rotation changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689544/android-dialog-etc-restore-after-rotation-changed)